# react js : how to animate a text array showing only one item at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, animation

I am very new to handle animations using ReactJS. I have been trying to animate a text array (ex `items: ["Text 1", "Text 2, "Text 3", ...]` in such a way that at a given point of time only one is visible and it keeps on looping through all the items. Without animations, its straight forward, but I want to achieve this **with animations** in place (like fading in/out etc)

I tried `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` but all the examples given in its docs cover only adding and removing to an array and showing all of them together.

This is what I have tried till now

```
export default class TextAnimate extends Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
                selectedText : this.props.items[0]
            }
            this.itemCounter = 0;
       }
    componentDidMount() {
            var context = this;
            if(this.props.items.length > 1){
                this.intervalTimer = window.setInterval(()=>{
                    context.setState({selectedText:this.props.items[context.itemCounter++]})
                    if(context.itemCounter == context.props.items.length){
                        context.itemCounter = 0;   
                    }
                },3000);
            }
        }
    render(){
            return(
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                    transitionName="example"
                    transitionAppear={true}
                    transitionAppearTimeout={1500}
                    transitionEnterTimeout={800}
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={800}>
                    <div className="item">
                        {this.state.selectedText}
                    </div>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just render only one item of the array everytime? You change your state of your component every x seconds to only render the n-th item of the array, and use ReactCSSTransitionGroup to animate the element entering and leaving

Comment: You might be interested in looking at react-motion library.

Comment: I just posted the code that i am trying, and the rendering of n-th item is working but not animating

Comment: You can do it with `framer motion`! Check out an equivalent tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_95SPKE6vg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with `framer-motion`:

```js
export default class TextAnimate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedText: this.props.items[0],
    };
    this.itemCounter = 0;
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.props.items;
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.length
          ? items.map((movie, i) => (
              <motion.li
                variants={itemVariants}
                initial="initial"
                animate="animate"
                transition={{ duration: 0.4, delay: i * 0.3 }}
                className="item">
                {this.state.selectedText}
              </motion.li>
            ))
          : null}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

By this, you `stagger` the items.
Check framer-motion here:

- https://www.framer.com/docs/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/framer-motion